# Let $W$ a subspace of $V$. Show that every element of $W^{*}$ is the restriction of an element of $V^{*}$ to $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

The question is:

Let $W$ a subspace of $V$. Show that every element of $W^{*}$ is the restriction of an element of $V^{*}$ to $W$.

I think that this question is true only if $\dim(V)<\infty$, cause we could use the fact that for every basis $\alpha$ for $W$, exists a dual basis $\alpha^{*}$ for $W^{*}$. But if $\dim(V)=\infty$, the set $\alpha^{*}$ is linearly independent but not necessarily a basis.

Comment: If you believe that every vector space has a basis, then every subspace has a complement and the statement becomes easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no norm or topology given, $V^*$ denotes the algebraic dual $\hom(V, K)$ where $K$ is the field of scalars. 
Then, using a form of axiom of choice (e.g. transfinite recursion), we can fix a basis $(w_i)$ for $W$, and extend it by elements $(v_j)$ to obtain a basis of $V$.

Then any linear $\alpha:W\to K$ can be extended to $V\to K$ by assigning arbitrary values (e.g. $0$) to the $v_j$'s.

---

If the infinite dimensional space $V$ is equipped with a norm, $V^*$ usually denotes the *topological dual* $\{\alpha:V\to K\mid\alpha$ is linear *and continuous*$\}$, but then we can use the Hahn-Banach theorem.